# Движки для интернет-магазина

Tags: python, php

Не подскажете, какие существуют бесплатные движки для построения интернет магазина? Интересует не хостинг, а именно исходники. Желательно на Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python + Django:

- [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/)
- [LFS](http://www.getlfs.com/start)

Answer (score 1):

[Satchless](http://satchless.com/): сам не пробовал, но слышал лестные отзывы.

Answer (score 0):

http://virtuemart.ru/
 очень даже не плохой

Answer (score 0):

Для небольшого интернет-магазина я бы рекомендовал [UnitCMS](http://unitcms.net) . Движок бесплатный и интуитивно понятен. Есть все необходимое. И главное оперативная техподдержка.